# How to validate a state data before pushing a new value into array in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Friends, I'm writing a drag and drop items example in ReactJs. I'm droping the items in a new div taking them in a new array. Now my new array(drop array) should validate not to drop the same item twise in my new div. I'm not getting how to validate the new dragged item with existing drop array.

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html00 lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>React JS Example 1</title>

<style>
    #div1 {width:350px;height:200px;padding:20px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <div id="container1"></div>
        <script src="react.js"></script>
        <script src="react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/babel">
            /*** @jsx React.DOM */



            var Employee = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function(){
                    return {data: [], empName: '',dropData:[]};
                },
                onClick: function(event){
                    this.state.data.push({empName: this.state.empName});
                    this.setState({empName: ''});
                },
                onNameChange: function(event){
                    this.setState({empName : event.target.value});
                },


            drag: function(event) {
            event.dataTransfer.setData("div", event.target.id);
                },
                render: function(){
                    return(
                    <div>

                            <h1> Add New Employees </h1>
                            Employee Name : <input type="text" value={this.state.empName} onChange={this.onNameChange}/>

                            <button onClick={this.onClick}>Add</button>

                        <ul>
                    {this.state.data.map(function(item, i) {

                        return (<li data-id={i} id={i} draggable="true" onDragStart={this.drag}>{item.empName}</li>)
                    }, this)}
                    {this.state.data.length > 0 ?<NewEmployee data={this.state.data}/> : null}
                </ul>
                </div>
                    )
                }
            });





            var NewEmployee = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function(){
                    return {data: this.props.data,dropData:[]};
                },
            allowDrop: function(event) {
                     event.preventDefault();
                },
                dropItem: function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var new_data = event.dataTransfer.getData("div"),
                    arr = this.state.dropData;
                    arr.push(this.props.data[new_item]);
                    this.setState({dropData: arr});
                },
                render: function(){
                    return(
                        <div  id="div1" onDrop={this.dropItem} onDragOver={this.allowDrop}>
                            {this.state.dropData.map(function(items, i) {
                        return (<li>{items.empName}</li>)
                    }, this)}
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            });

            ReactDOM.render(<Employee/>, document.getElementById('container'));

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var NewEmployee = React.createClass({
        getInitialState: function(){
                return {data: this.props.data,dropData:[]};
            },
        allowDrop: function(event) {
                 event.preventDefault();
            },
            dropItem: function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var new_data = event.dataTransfer.getData("div"),
                arr = this.state.dropData;
                if(arr.indexOf(new_data) > -1) {
                   arr = arr.slice();
                   arr.push(this.props.data[new_data]);  
                   this.setState({dropData: arr});                        
                }


            },
            render: function(){
                return(
                    <div  id="div1" onDrop={this.dropItem} onDragOver={this.allowDrop}>
                        {this.state.dropData.map(function(items, i) {
                    return (<li>{items.empName}</li>)
                }, this)}
                    </div>
                )
            }
        });
```